# stop java execution if condition is met

Tags: java

So the idea is a kind of virtual classroom (a website) where students uploads uncompiled .java files, our server will compile it and execute it through C# or PHP, the language doesn't matter, creating a .bat file and get the feedback of the console if the program compiled correctly or not and if the execution was correct based on some pre-maded test, so far our tests did work but we have completely no control on what's inside the .java file so we want to stop the execution if some criterias did happen, i.e. an user input, infite loop, sockets instances, etc... I've digging on internet if there's a way to configure the java environment to avoid this but so far can't find anything, and we don't want our backend language to go through the file to check this things cause will be a completly mess up

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could configure a security manager, but it [doesn't have a very good track record of stopping a determined attacker](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57646/why-do-i-hear-about-so-many-java-insecurities-are-other-languages-more-secure), and doesn't do resource limiting anyways.

You could load the untrusted code with a dedicated class loader that only sees white-listed classes.

Or you could use something like docker to isolate the process at the operating system level. This could also limit its cpu and memory consumption.

I'd probably combine these approaches, but some risk will remain in either case.

(Yes, I realize that is complex, but safely sandboxing arbitrary java code is a hard problem.)